# get element inside of an element not yet posted on a page

Tags: javascript

I am creating a div using javascript and posting an ajax response into it:

```
    var tempdiv = document.createElement('div');
    tempdiv.setAttribute('id','tempcontent');
    tempdiv.setAttribute('style','display:none');
    tempdiv.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
    var newarticle = tempdiv.getElementsByTagName('article');
    content.appendChild(newarticle);
```

Somehow `newarticle` is undefined. probably because the js cannot explore the code posted without it being posted to the page first. Any workaround for this? another way to write it?

Comment: You could just append the tempDiv to the page first but hidden?

Comment: `newarticle` cannot be `undefined`. But `content.appendChild` cannot work since `newarticle` is a node list, not a single element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName` returns a `NodeList` of elements with the specified tag name. `appendChild` expects a single node.

Try `content.appendChild(newarticle[0])`